# How to pass a parameter to a middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization, middleware

I have this route in my `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/checkout', [CheckoutController::class, 'index'])->name('checkoutIndex')->middleware('auth');
```

My `CheckoutController`:

```
 function index()
{
    if (Cart::instance('default')->count() == 0) {
        return redirect()->route('cartIndex', App::getLocale())->withErrors('Your shopping cart is empty! Please select an item to checkout.');
    }

    $discount = session()->has('coupon') ? session()->get('coupon')['discount'] : 0;

    return view('checkout_index')->with(['lang' => App::getLocale(), 'discount' => $discount]);
}
```

When I'm not logged in and go to the URL it takes me to a login page as it should. but the login page gives a `Missing required parameter for [Route: login] [URI: {lang}/login] [Missing parameter: lang].` error.

The login page works well in its own route anywhere else in the app, I only get the error by clicking on this one specific link:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary text-light p-3 rounded-0" href="{{ route('checkoutIndex', App::getLocale()) }}">{{__('Proceed to Checkout')}}</a>
```

I believe having middleware is causing the issue.

I'm using the laravel built-in auth. the route to login is `Auth::routes();`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using the laravel built-in auth. the route to login is `Auth::routes();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this

in your App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate middleware

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

You need to pass the required parameter to the route:

```
return route('login', ['lang' => App::getLocale()])
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary text-light p-3 rounded-0" href="{{ route('checkoutIndex', App::getLocale()) }}">{{__('Proceed to Checkout')}}</a>
```

to

```
<a class="btn btn-primary text-light p-3 rounded-0" href="{{ route('checkoutIndex', ['lang' => App::getLocale()) ] }}">{{__('Proceed to Checkout')}}</a>
```